# Security problems with server

Tags: laravel, security, server

guys I just want to ask a couple of questions about security problems, if this is not the place to ask these questions then please close the question.

I want to make a web application with Laravel where u can watch movies (it would be used only by me and a few friends of mine). I'm going to turn my old pc into a server and use it for the app. My questions are: (if the answers are too long then please provide a link where I could read about this).

What can a hacker do if he hacks into my server (don't care about data that much since there will be no personal information inside of it) and how to prevent it? Keep in mind I don't want to pay for any firewalls if it's not absolutely necessary.
if the hackers gain access into my server and the server is connected to my router. Can he gain access to the router and then other devices connected to the router. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Broadly speaking in security the question is not how to prevent attacks it's all about mitigation and making things as hard as possible. You can't really ever prevent attacks because software would always have bugs and those bugs may result in all sorts of attacks. You can, however you can make it hard enough to not make it worth the time of any attacker. Your use case doesn't really sound like a prime target of serious attacks so just the basics of implementing some authentication and sanitising inputs and queries is probably good enough

Comment: It's not the right place actually, try [security.se].